# dhtmlxgrid server-side sorting and pagination

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I have a grid that is supposed to display a big dataset. I used server-side sorting to sort the data, but now my problem is that the data gets sorted, but it only shows the first page.

Normally, `GET` variables are sent when the page is changed (posStart and count). But after I do the sorting it doesn't send those variables. It sends nothing, which is why the other pages aren't displaying anything.

**Update**

I have the following code:

```
    mygrid.attachEvent("onBeforeSorting",function(ind,type,direction){
    window.a_direction = direction;       
    window.s_col = ind;      
    var grid = this;     
    grid.setSortImgState(true,window.s_col,window.a_direction);              
    grid.clearAndLoad("getEscalations.php?endDate="+$('#endDate').val()+"&startDate="+$('#startDate').val()+"&dir="+window.a_direction+"&ind="+window.s_col+"&surveyID="+$('#surveyID').val(),function(){
        grid.setSortImgState(true,window.s_col,window.a_direction);     
    });  
});
```

Now that is for sorting the data, now after I run this function that's when the problem comes up, only populates the first page.

Comment: Naiza, welcome to SO. Could you highlight your actual question some more, please?

Comment: You should show some of your code if you want people to be able to actually assist you, rather than having to second-guess what's happening.